# Creating an alias for a python script

Tags: python, bash, terminal

I'm new to python programming. I want to create an alias  to my script, so that i can use it in the terminal.

I've a .py file named r.py and i'm trying to create an alias for it. I created it by using the following commnad:

```
$ alias new="python /Python_scripts/radians.py"
```

Now when i type the word new in the terminal it's giving an error -'no such file exists'

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Is your path correct? Are you trying to use an 'absolute path' or a 'relative path'? You can run 'readlink -m radians.py' to get the absolute path to your python script and then update your alias with that instead.

Comment: In bash syntax no space is allowed around `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is probably not correct:

```
alias new="python /Python_scripts/radians.py"
```

will try to find the Python_scripts directory at the root level while I assume it would be in your home directory. Try replacing it with a relative path

```
alias new="python Python_scripts/radians.py"
```

or, better, with

```
alias new="python ~/Python_scripts/radians.py"
```

so that you can run the aliased command from anywhere.

Comment: `$HOME` is preferred over `~` for portability.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How so? `~` is also defined by the POSIX standard to refer to the current user's home directory. True, there are situations where you cannot use `~`, but this is not one of them, and that's a matter of correctness, not portability.